# Cambio formato fecha al publicar

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, vb.net, iis

Tengo un selector donde aparece el nombre de una receta, al seleccionar una de ellas se completa un gridview. El gridview se completa con la fecha y hora de cada acción.

Si pruebo el sitio web desde el emulador de Visual Studio, el formato de fecha en la vista de cuadrícula parece correcto (es el mismo en la base de datos), el formato es: AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

Sin embargo, cuando publico el sitio web para acceder desde IIS, la vista de cuadrícula es la misma pero el formato de fecha cambió a: dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss.

He mirado formatos de fecha en sql, formato de fecha de windows, todo parece correcto.

También intenté filtrar con un selector de fecha y hora y selecciona el formato correctamente.

Comment: Hola amigo, la fecha que muestra viene dada por la configuración regional que tenga el servidor o bien la maquina donde estás corriendo la aplicación, por lo que los formatos de fecha pueden variar teniendo en cuenta esta variable. Saludos